# View to display content type and media type

Tags: views, media

Drupal 8

Say I have 1 content type and 2 media types users can create
Content type: Post
Media Type: Picture
Media type: Movie

How can I create a view that pulls all 3? As far as I can see you can only create views that show content, or media but not both in the same view.

I wasnt to create a feed displaying all 3 types of all users on the site.

Comment: Which version of Drupal?

Comment: there is no relationship between the content and media though.  I already checked into that once,  But if I create a new View to display content and then go to add a relationship, Media is not one of the options.


Just to clarify I want to display all published nodes from Content Type: Post, Media Type: Picture, Media Type: Movie.  From ALL users on the site.  I could do this on an individual users page using relationships as the User has a relationship to all but there is nothing that connects the posts from everyone.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no relationships among the three entity types, as you have indicated in comments, you could use attachments or blocks. (I'm assuming you want a page that displays all the information.)

**Attachment Solution:**

- Create your View with a page display of one of the entity types.
- In the same View create two attachment displays, and use overrides to base them off the other entity types. Attach them to the page display.

**Block Solution:**

- Create your View with a page display of one of the entity types.
- Create additional, separate, Views of each of the other entity types, with block displays
- Use the block configuration system to place those blocks on the page display

Comment: While this would work depending on what you want the final output to look like.  I want the final output to be a "pinterest" style feed.  And neither of these solutions would get me the data in a way where I could make that style feed.  I think I will have to have the page custom programmed out to pull from multiple tables in the database.   Thank you though, both are very good suggestions

Comment: No problem. I do recommend that you add this information to your post, along with some details about the three entity types. It will help you get more precisely tailored answers.